# Bluetooth HC05 doesn't go into AT Mode (No Key Pin)

Tags: bluetooth

I'm currently working out a project using an HC05 Bluetooth module but before I get into the actual coding, I need to configure it as a Master module. From the datasheet: To get into command or AT mode, I turn off the module, set the Key Pin to high and turn the module on. This however won't work for me as I don't have a Key pin however, I have here an EN pin instead of the Key pin shown in the picture.

[image]

I tried setting the EN pin to high but it doesn't respond OK when I enter 'AT'. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. Try the [Electronics/EE StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some bluetooth modules doesn't have the 'Key Pin' and unfortunately, that 'EN' pin is not the same as the 'Key Pin'. What you can do however is short PIN 34 to the VCC before turning on the module. This will make the module enter into the AT mode. Be sure to keep it there if you want the full AT mode to stay. Refer to the datasheet [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwid88Wi3cTKAhWjIaYKHbT3AsQQFggtMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thaieasyelec.com%2Fdownloads%2FEFDV390%2FEFDV390_Datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGFrtTC2LY80dCWibyzsbzQora1Zg&sig2=dWsxKukedG6CRvsJTXz__w&cad=rja) for your reference. Pin 34 is PIO11 which is the pin located in the upper right.

Comment: Wiill get back to you. Trying it out.

Comment: Thaaaanks! I need to solder that pin though. Thanks again!